# Como posso gerir bilbiotecas JavaScript no meu projecto PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, composer, biblioteca

Tenho um projecto em PHP e uso o [composer](https://getcomposer.org) para gerir bibliotecas como por exemplo o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para envio de e-mails.

Para poder utilizar as bibliotecas instaladas basta-me incluir o autoload do composer:

```
require ('vendor/autoload.php');
```

Recentemente também precisei de usar outras bibliotecas, mas são bibliotecas JavaScript, e fiz o mesmo procedimento acima descrito. O «problema» é que tenho de fazer a inclusão dos ficheiros JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/NovaBiblioteca/js/nova.mim.js">
```

Ao fim da segunda biblioteca usada não me parece nada intuitivo.

Como é que eu posso fazer a gestão de bibliotecas JavaScript?

Comment: Parece um caso de uso do npm, não do composer.

Comment: @bfavaretto ando a ler e só vejo npm ligado a Node e bower ligado a JS, CSS e HTML. Podes-me esclarecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O composer é um gerenciador de pacotes PHP, você não <strike>pode</strike> deve instalar bibliotecas Javascript por ele, você teria que utilizar um outro gerenciador de pacotes específico para Javascript como NPM, yarn, bower ou webpack, sendo que no código javascript poderia usar o webpack para injetar automaticamente as bibliotecas usadas num só arquivo a ser incluído.

Veja aqui como usar o webpack https://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-webpack/

Comment: Mas o engraçado é que eu consigo também incluir pacotes de JavaScript por ele. Estão disponíveis quando faço `composer require PacoteJS`.

Comment: Sim, é possível importar estes pacotes usando o composer: https://gist.github.com/odan/b5812c61d494d45becabaaf223875bb3 e https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184666/how-to-add-javascript-or-css-library-to-composer-project tanto CSS e JS mas o Composer é um gerenciador de pacotes PHP, daí seu repositório não tem todas as bibliotecas JS como o yarn/bower e não seria oficialmente suportado, te levando a poder ter problemas futuros com algumas bibliotecas JS

Comment: Interessante saber isso, é que não é só uma questão de simplificar as coisas, pode também ter influência a nível de funcionamento...

Comment: Sim, a separação de gerenciadores facilita a compatibilidade dos pacotes JS apesar de adicionar uma camada de complexidade, o uso do webpack que sugeri é por poder fazer um bundle de dependências js num arquivo (bundle.js) minificado unificado a ser incluído no PHP que facilita a manutenção de código PHP

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu tentaria usar primeiro só o NPM, sem webpack. Talvez com gulp. O problema do webpack é que ele faz várias coisas a mais (permite separar o código final em pacotes/módulos que podem ser carregados on-demand), e a curva de aprendizado não é muito amigável. Eu, pelo menos, sofri um pouco pra aprender.